# Find changes in RavenDb session

Tags: c#, ravendb

How can I find out what entities have been modified/changed in RavenDb session?

Comment: In a "normal" database, the answer is "add a time modified" column".  For RavenDB, you should also be able to use the Changes API: http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/changes-api

Comment: He's talking about changes within the session.  Not changes to the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot iterate through a list of changes.  However, you can do a few simple things:

```
// check if an entity has been modified
session.Advanced.HasChanged(entity)

// check if there are any changes at all
session.Advanced.HasChanges
```

If you are trying to do something on all entities that have changed, you can wire up a [DocumentStoreListener](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/client-side-listeners#document-store-listener).